# Height of flex element is not respected unless display: table is set?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/u2zedzob/12/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main-content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

.footer {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: table;
}
```

In this example, the footer's height is 30px and main-content grows to fill the rest of the space. Perfect!

However, if I remove the `display: table` property of footer -- its height becomes 27.266px. This can also be prevented by setting the footer's min-height to 30px.

I'm not too familiar with flex logic. Why is this happening? Is there a more elegant solution where the height of footer will be respected? Maybe a flex property I am missing?

Comment: If you use css clear the div with class wrapper, your height will be respected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with flex box model you do not need to set `height` property for the child elements which should scale. Instead you would use e.g. the `flex-grow` property. In the given case where just one element should be scaled a value of `1` would be appropriate (as no proportions need to be defined here).

Have a look at the updated example where the height of the `.main-content` element is scaled according to the available space and the height of the `.footer` element is retained correctly by `30px` without setting the `display` property:

http://jsfiddle.net/u2zedzob/21/

For further information maybe check this guide:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The `flex-grow` property is explained as:

> This defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It
>   accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion. It dictates what
>   amount of the available space inside the flex container the item
>   should take up.
>
> If all items have flex-grow set to 1, every child will set to an equal
>   size inside the container. If you were to give one of the children a
>   value of 2, that child would take up twice as much space as the
>   others.